# How to handle double quotes in xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have a XPATH:

```
"//*[@id='TEST_0'][disabled=""]"
```

But I am getting error at the end ") required". Is there a way we can handle double quotations with in xpath?

Comment: google knows... please spend a few minutes googling the answer to your own question before asking.

Answer (score 2):

That's actually related to language you are using. Use *(\)* escape character

Answer (score 2):

Why not just write

```
"//*[@id='TEST_0'][disabled='']"
```

It only starts to be a problem when you need both double and single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you suggestion. It did work

```
("//*[@id='Test_0'][disabled=" + "\"\"" + "]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do it:

```
@"//*[@id='TEST_0'][disabled=""]"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way

```
"//*[@id='TEST_0'][disabled="\""\"]"
```

Example :

```
System.out.print("\"Hello\"");
```

This will print: "Hello" in double qoutes